# Position a div to left:0 of window (not parent)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok this is kinda hard to explain. I want a div that is inside another div to break outside its parent and take the full width of the window. I also want it to be of coursed positioned at the left side of the window. The div can't be position with `position: fixed;` as it needs to scroll with the rest of the page.

That div will eventually have an image inside it. Unfortunately I can't exactly described it with words and I don't have the reputation to upload an image but you can see what I mean at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fRVK/1/)

So I've written this code so far

```
function sizeit(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    $('.imgfull').css({'width':windowWidth });
    console.log("width= " + windowWidth)
    var offset = $('.imgfull').offset();
    $('.imgfull').css({'right':offset.left});
    console.log("Offset left=" + offset.left)
}


$(window).ready(function () {
    sizeit();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    sizeit();
});
```

Now this seems to work just fine when I load the page. The div gets the right width from `$('.imgfull').css({'width':windowWidth });` and it gets positioned correctly with '$('.imgfull').css({'right':offset.left});'

The problem is that if I resize the window then the positioning gets off. The `console.log("Offset left=" + offset.left)` is reporting 2 values. If I remove the line '$('.imgfull').css({'right':offset.left});' then console shows only one correct value. So it seems like just moving the div through css `right':offset.left` is causing the offset to get wrong values.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply make use of the css property:
Position: fixed

Comment: Ah I forgot to mention that this happens in a long page where the div in question needs to scroll with the rest of the page. I'll edit my original question to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Never mind found the solution. Instead of using `var offset = $('.imgfull').offset();` I simply get the offset of the wrapper ( `var offset = $('#wrap').offset();` ) thus solving the problem. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7fRVK/5/)